# Help in luring our missing since two weeks cat, which we've recently spotted in our neighbourhood

Tags: cats, lost-pet

Please help me in my attempts to lure our cat! Our cat has been missing for two weeks and we saw her today few neighborhoods down.

[As mentioned in one of my previous questions, our cat went missing two weeks ago](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/27660/17671). Thanks to some help we received in the recent three days, we have spotted out cat wandering on two specific streets, a few neighbourhoods away from our home. We have set three traps in the area this morning and we are watching them. Today she came right in front of me as I was in my car watching from across the trap. I did not want to get out - according to what a pet catcher told me, she may run to a different area if I call her, as she likely turned feral now and may think I am chasing her.

If I see her in the next few days while I am watching the trap, should I wait until she gets in one of the traps? Or can I call her name hoping she still remembers it and will come to me? I kind of regret not getting out of my car and trying to say her name today, but then I remembered the professional's words. The pet catcher told us we have to observe her roaming patterns at different times of the day and try to trap her based on that, is this accurate?

Comment: Two weeks is not enough time for a cat to turn feral, though she may be skittish. Did you bait the traps? What did you use? Do you have one near your house?

Comment: Yes we have four traps and are watching over them with four people. There is a local dog and cat catcher non profit helping us and she told us to avoid approaching our cat if we see her and just watch and wait for the traps to go off. We put her food and smelly fish that she likes for the food in the traps. No luck so far but only been a day. We are quite a bit away from our home( she was mainly indoor cat) so I’m guessing the storm two weeks ago brought her here. Just a few hours ago she was in a house right in front of me where I had a trap nearby but she went in the opposite direction

Comment: I wanted to get out of the car and call her name but I was told by the pet catcher just to stay calm and observe her patterns in th area and we will catch her via traps