# Indoor cat got out and she is in heat

Tags: cats

My indoor cat got out a couple nights ago and I’ve been looking for her every night with no success in finding her. Will she come back after she gets pregnant? Will she be able to find her way back because she is an indoor cat? What can I do? I’ve already put her litter box outside plus food and water.

Comment: Related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/27660/what-else-can-we-do-to-find-our-missing-cat-2-days-now

Comment: Welcome To Pet Exchange, does your cat have an identification chip or tattoos? What country are you in?